# Ghost.py not finding PySide?

Tags: python, macos, webkit, screen-scraping, ghost.py

I'm trying to get started with the [Ghost.py](https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py/blob/master/ghost/ghost.py) headless browser on a Mac. I installed Ghost.py and its dependencies using these links/commands:

1. [Qt 5.0.1 for Mac](http://qt-project.org/downloads), has a GUI installer
2. [PySide 1.1.0](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aLanguageBindings%3a%3aPySide%3a%3aDownloads), which requires `Qt Version >= 4.7.4`, has a GUI installer
3. `sudo pip install Ghost.py`

I launched Python, and confirmed that I can `import PySide`. However, when I do `from ghost import Ghost`, **it fails to find PySide**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghost/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ghost import Ghost
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghost/ghost.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise Exception("Ghost.py requires PySide or PyQt")
Exception: Ghost.py requires PySide or PyQt
```

By doing `import PySide; print PySide;`, it appears that PySide is installed here on my system: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide`. So, appended the `PYTHONPATH` like this: 
`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages #for PySide`.

However, `Ghost.py` still cannot find `PySide`.

**How can I convince `Ghost.py` to find my installation of `PySide`?**

---

Environment:

- Mac OS X 10.7.5
- Python 2.7
- Qt 5.0.1
- PySide 1.1.0

Comment: Try making a Python file with just `from ghost import Ghost` in it. Then try running that under `pdb` like `python -m pdb import-ghost.py`. Then step through it seeing if you can find what particular `import` statement within `ghost.py` fails.

Comment: Aha, it fails when trying to do `from PySide import QtWebKit`. It looks like the real problem is that PySide's WebKit wrapper can't find a suitable QtWebKit binary on my system. I'm seeing if I can find the appropriate path for QtWebKit now.

Comment: I installed `Qt 4.8` (instead of `Qt 5.0.1`) from [this link](http://qt-project.org/downloads), and PySide started working properly.

Comment: Im getting the same error and I have installed Qt 4.8.5 from the same link but to no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exact same problem but managed to fix it. Here is how:

1. Uninstall the current installation of PySide and qt on your system. Make sure PySide is not present in  `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`.
2. Install qt and PySide from http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_MacOSX.

PS: My system is running 10.9 (Mavericks) but I think it should work in 10.7 (Mountain Lion) as well.