# Ghost.py not Finding PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside, ghost.py

I am working on a script and require Ghost.py for working with Javascript. I installed Qt and Pyside but this error keeps coming when i try to execute my document.

> Exception: Ghost.py requires PySide or PyQt

I am doing this in my .py file before rest of the code.

```
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()
```

I have tried everything I could find on SO(especially this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047426/ghost-py-not-finding-pyside)) and the web including adding path environment variable. I also uninstalled and re-installed PySide and Ghost but the same error keeps on coming.

Any help in this direction would be greatly appreciated.

*Environment*

- Windows 8
- Python 2.7
- Qt 4.8.5
- PySide 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the PyQT framework?

Comment: Yes I am not using PyQt. Either PySide or PyQt works with Ghost. It says in here. http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_FAQ